# Groupby when given the start positional index of each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have one series of values that I would like to group, and another series containing the starting positional index of each group after the first (the first group is understood to begin at positional index 0). The series of values can have an arbitrary index. Is there a way to use this to produce a groupby-aggregate? Ideally empty groups would be preserved. Example:

```
values = pd.Series(np.arange(10, 20), index=np.arange(110, 120))
group_indices = pd.Series([3, 3, 8])
```

Now, `values.groupby(group_indices)` should be grouped so that the first group is `values.iloc[:3]`, the second is `values.iloc[3:3]` (an empty group), the third is `values.iloc[3:8]`, and the fourth is `values.iloc[8:]`, and `values.groupby(group_indices).mean()` would be `pd.Series([11.0, NaN, 15.0, 18.5])`.

Comment: would turning the series into a dataframe work for you?

Comment: @Yuca Sure, as long as it gets the job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the answers, especially [WeNYoBen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57593797/5496433). The following will produce the correct groups and skip over empty groups.

```
# First, add the final index to `group_indices` so that
# we have a series of right endpoints, or interval upper bounds
upper_bounds = group_indices.append(pd.Series(values.shape[0]), ignore_index=True)

# Compute indices of nonempty groups
lower_bounds = upper_bounds.shift(fill_value=0)
nonempty_group_idxs = upper_bounds != lower_bounds

# Get means indexed from 0 to n_nonempty_groups-1
means = values.groupby(pd.RangeIndex(values.shape[0]).isin(upper_bounds).cumsum()).mean()

# Reassign index for the correct groups
means.index = nonempty_group_idxs.index[nonempty_group_idxs]
```

This will have a noncontinuous index, with skipped elements corresponding to empty groups in the original `groupby`. If you want to place `NaN` in those spots, you can do

```
means = means.reindex(index=pd.RangeIndex(group_indices.shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Straightforwardly with [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) routine:

```
In [1286]: values = pd.Series(np.arange(10, 20))

In [1287]: group_indices = pd.Series([0, 3, 8])

In [1288]: pd.Series([s.mean() for s in np.split(values, group_indices) if s.size])
Out[1288]: 
0    11.0
1    15.0
2    18.5
dtype: float64
```

---

To account "empty" group - just remove `if s.size` check:

```
In [1304]: group_indices = pd.Series([3, 3, 8])

In [1305]: pd.Series([s.mean() for s in np.split(values, group_indices)])
Out[1305]: 
0    11.0
1     NaN
2    15.0
3    18.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @BallpointBen To account "empty" group - just skip `if s.size` check

Answer (score 3):

Here is a easy way

```
values.groupby(values.index.isin(group_indices).cumsum()).mean()
Out[454]: 
1    11.0
2    15.0
3    18.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep empty groups this way? See the edit to my question.

Comment: @BallpointBenB no cumsum will not create the empty group, you need to check with pd.cut `values.groupby(pd.cut(values.index,pd.Series([0,3, 3, 8]).drop_duplicates())).mean()
`

Answer (score 1):

Given your update, here's an odd way to do this with `pd.merge_asof`. Some care needs to be taken to deal with the first group that's from 0 to your first index in the Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

(pd.merge_asof(values.to_frame('val'), 
               values.iloc[np.r_[group_indices]].reset_index().reset_index().drop(columns=0), 
               left_index=True, right_on='index',
               direction='backward')
   .fillna({'level_0': -1})          # Because your first group is 0: first index
   .groupby('level_0').val.mean()
   .reindex([-1]+[*range(len(group_indices))])  # Get 0 size groups in output
)
```

---

```
level_0
-1    11.0
 0     NaN
 1    15.0
 2    18.5
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I like the usage of ffill :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the group_indicies a bit, so that the group names (1,2,3) are visible,

```
group_indices = pd.Series([1,2,3],index=[0, 3, 8])
```

then

```
values.groupby(group_indices.reindex(values.index,method='ffill')).mean()
```

would give you what you want.

Note that `group_indices.reindex(values.index,method='ffill')` gives you

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    3
9    3
```

which assigns each row of `values` with a group number.

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves keeping the inputs as they are and doing some ugly adjustments:

```
pd.DataFrame(values).assign(group=pd.cut(pd.DataFrame(values).index,
                     [-1,2,7,np.inf], labels=[0,1,2])).groupby('group').mean()
```

Output

```
          0
group      
0      11.0
1      15.0
2      18.5
```